# What does it mean - to get billed to the 95th percentile at $x.xx per meg?

Tags: bandwidth, colocation, bandwidth-measuring

I got a quote from a colo, saying

> "I could do 3U, the power and 20 megs burstable to 100 for $250 a
>   month with each additional meg billed to the 95th percentile at 6.50
>   per meg..so you would have he ability to burst if you needed it but
>   not pay for the full 24/7 amount of the IP."

I'm assuming it means - 20Mbits unmetered, anything above is billed on the 95th percentile at the rate of $6.50/Mbit. Am I right? And how do you measure the $x.xx per meg, at 95th percentile?

Comment: Don't you think it would be more productive to ask your host to clarify this instead of asking us to guess at their terms?

Comment: I asked the guy way too many questions already:) Plus I want a third-party explanation, before I jump into this offer.

Comment: A bit of advice: make your sales people earn their money :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It basically means throwing away the top 5% of samples of the bandwidth used above the 20-megabit/second contract rate... This is an unmetered link, so you can use 100 megabits/second when you need it... but the average usage needs to be below 20 megabit/second. The purpose is to determine your realistic and sustained usage pattern.

This is also [described in greater detail in the Wikipedia "Burstable Billing" article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burstable_billing).

Comment: What does it mean when it says - "at 6.50 per meg"? Does it mean that extra bandwidth is charged at $6,500 per TB of bandwidth?

Comment: $6.50 per each additional Megabit-per-second *above* your contracted rate of 20 Megabits/second.

Comment: Got it! Everything makes sense now!