# 100 Mbit/s Colocation Connectivity

Tags: networking, web-hosting, dedicated-server, colocation

I have an offer for 100 Mbit/s network speed in as a co-location service.

100mbit includes download/upload all together?

For example: Can I upload with 100Mbit/s while downloading 100Mbit/s at same time?

Comment: You really should be asking your colo provider. How can we know what their policies are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this should be full-duplex bandwidth... But check the terms of the offer to make sure that language is there.

Make sure you understand the billing metrics. For instance, unmetered and burstable/95th percentile are vastly different and need to be planned for...

Also see: [What does it mean - to get billed to the 95th percentile at $x.xx per meg?](https://serverfault.com/questions/423415/what-does-it-mean-to-get-billed-to-the-95th-percentile-at-x-xx-per-meg)